# put for loop in dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, count

First time here can anyone tell me how to put this loop in a dict comprehension?

```
counts = {}
for word in words:
    if word in counts:
        counts[word] = counts[word] + 1
    else:
        counts[word] = 1
print(counts)
```

Comment: Comprehensions cannot refer to the list or dict they are generating. Try using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead.

Comment: In Dict or List comprehension you can't possible update existing elements. Indeed it can only create new elements